# How can I export DBeaver connection configurations?

Tags: dbeaver

I was hoping there is a way to export DBeaver connection configurations/properties from my old machine rather than having to go through the process of recreating each one.  Does anyone know how to do this?

The DBeaver version on my old machine is 6.0.3, and the version on my new machine is 6.1.x.

Answer (score 142):

I just migrated some projects from DBeaver 6.1.4 to 7.2.3 and the File > Export/Import options worked flawlessly.

The full workflow is:

1. File > Export, under "DBeaver", select "Project", click Next
2. Select the projects to export and click Finish
3. Copy the output file (by default, it is generated in home folder) into the machine where the projects will be imported
4. File > Import, under "DBeaver", select "Project", click Next
5. Select the file generated in the previous steps, it will automatically load the projects from it.
6. Select the projects to import, if there is any name conflict you can change the name of the imported project. Click Finish.

IMHO, very complete, easy and straightforward.

**Update**: after a few days of working, I realized some of the connections were not imported. I still don't know why, but it seems to be a bug. Just double check your connections after exporting and importing.

Comment: This is the best answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It's good to use import/export functionality provided by Dbeaver instead of doing it manually by locating the Dbeaver data directory and using it in new Dbeaver setup. That directory might contain some unnecessary data e.g. logs, temporary files etc. If there is version mismatch, copying data manually might result in some abnormal behavior.

Answer (score 63):

My experience on **Windows** 10 x64 for 
migrate connections from **DBeaver 5.1.2** to **DBeaver 6.1.5**:

`File | Export` and `File | Import` functionality is (at least) not easy/clear.
(Where are the "connection strings"? What should I export?)

So, I found these files:

- **DBeaver 5:**

  > C:\Users\user-123\.dbeaver4\General\.dbeaver-data-sources.xml

  (it was clearly updated from version 4)
- **DBeaver 6:**

  > C:\Users\user-456\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\workspace6\General\.dbeaver\data-sources.json

So, I have to manually extract the data from XML and put in the JSON.
I hope you have the JSON configuration file for both 6.3 and 6.1.x.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 63):

On OSX (Mac) here:

```
/Users/${USER}/Library/DBeaverData/workspace6/General/.dbeaver/
```

Comment: Best answer for MacOS users; copying that folder did the trick!

Comment: My needs was about the transfer all data from macos to linux, this did the work and I don't have to reconfigure nothing.

Answer (score 45):

On Ubunutu, For Dbeaver 6, it is found in

```
$HOME/.local/share/DBeaverData/workspace6/General/.dbeaver
```

Answer (score 25):

For Microsoft Windows users the files can be found under:

```
C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\workspace6\General\.dbeaver
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me find the file. However, there is something else at play here... because DBeaver just started up without showing my connections, that were still visible in this .dbeaver file.  I think there is some sort of correlation with project folders too, but a missing or moved project folder seems to lead to issues with not showing connections?

Answer (score 13):

DBeaver connections are stored in file `.dbeaver-data-sources.xml`, in DBeaver workspace, which is in `%{HOME/.dbeaver4/General/` by default.

Answer (score 10):

connections are now stored in a file named `data-sources.json` as you can check [here](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Admin-Manage-Connections)

on my Ubuntu I lost my connections cause I downloaded the new version using snap

I solved it just copying that file from old path `~/.local/share/.DBeaverData/workspace6/General/.dbeaver/`

to my new path `~/snap/dbeaver-ce/90/.local/share/DBeaverData/workspace6/General/.dbeaver`

Answer (score 9):

In my case the path is:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\workspace6\General\.dbeaver
```

If the folder **.dbeaver** does not exist in a fresh installation you will need to create.

The beaver version: 7.3

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu 20.04, Snap installed:
Dbeaver version: 7.1.2

Connections:
~/snap/dbeaver-ce/61/.local/share/DBeaverData/workspace6/General/.dbeaver/

Scripts:
/home/shiwakant/snap/dbeaver-ce/61/.local/share/DBeaverData/workspace6/General/Scripts/

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the Windows Store DBeaver CE Application on Windows 10 the workspace folder is different because of the app sandboxing and looks like this:

```
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Packages\DBeaverCorp.DBeaverCE_<SANDBOXING_HASH>\LocalCache\Roaming\DBeaverData\workspace6\
```

Then you can follow the Wiki instructions here:

https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Admin-Manage-Connections/

Comment: This answer saved the day !

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, just copy these folders and files from the location `%APPDATA%\DBeaverData\workspace6\General`:

- .dbeaver\
- Scripts\
- .dbeaver-data-sources.xml

Paste it at the target (a new installation of DBeaver doesn't have the above file and folders). The connections will appear and work. I just tested this a few minutes ago and wanted to document it.

Comment: In my windows, %APPDATA%  already include the "\Roaming" path, so, the path should be  %APPDATA%\DBeaverData\workspace6\General

Comment: ur right, I have edited the path to reflect it

Answer (score 2):

I've just tried to move configuration for dbeaver 7.3.1 from one win machine to another, and if you copy&paste folder:

> C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\

you will get everything works quite smoothly

Answer (score 1):

just copy paste both data-sources.json and credentials-config.json from C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\workspace6\General.dbeaver

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clone all current connections to another macOS:

From your macOS, go to this folder: `/Users/username/Library/DBeaverData/workspace6/General/`

You will see folder `.dbeaver`

Copy this folder and send to another macOS with same directory.

Answer (score 0):

DBeaver 6.1.3+

+project connections in the file:C:\Users\ [USER]\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\workspace6\General.dbeaver\data-sources.json

+All secured information files: C:\Users\ [USER]\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\workspace6\General.dbeaver\credentials-config.json